# How to rename/keep the callback methods

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a function that checks that the callback methods within an object exist. Currently  the Closure Compiler renames the methods (onClickDisplay and onCloseHide) so all the checks in makeCallbacks() fail.

Is there a way to tell the Closure Compiler to not rename the methods (onClickDisplay and onCloseHide) or tell the Compiler to also rename the method names in callbackNames()

```
makeCallbacks = function(tobject, methodNames) {
 var callbacks = {};

 methodNames.each(function(methodName) {
    if (!tobject[methodName]) {
     throw new Error(methodName + ' missing from ' + tobject.toString());
    }
    callbacks[methodName] = tobject[methodName].bind(tobject);
 });

 return callbacks;
};


FeedbackController = Class.create({
  initialize: function(id, item) {
   this.callbacks = makeCallbacks(this, this.callbackNames());
  },

  observeElements: function() {
   $$(this.id + ' .closeme').invoke('observe', 'click', this.callbacks.onCloseHide);
  },

  callbackNames: function() {
   return ['onClickDisplay', 'onCloseHide'];
  },

  onClickDisplay: function(e) {
   // do something
  },

  onCloseHide: function(e) {
   // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: This might not be what you want to hear... but usually you simply expect your objects to have those methods instead of explicitely checking for it. If you need that, consider using a language that is statically typed.

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly tell the closure compiler not to rename variables by doing :

```
goog.exportProperty(FeedbackController, 'onClickDisplay', FeedbackController.onClickDisplay);
```

Or by including a custom externs file with your methods :

```
function onClickDisplay() {};
function onCloseHide() {};
```

and providing that to the closure compiler:

```
"--externs=/externs/externs.js"
```

This will prevent it from renaming the variables. Typically you would only use this for interacting with an external library though.

source : [Closure the Definitive Guide](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9781449381882/exports/id3302838)

Answer (score 1):

The coding style you are using is violating one of the central requirements of Closure-compiler with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS: consistent property access. Namely, you cannot refer to the same property using a mix of dotted notation `obj.prop` and quoted `obj['prop']`. You can quote your property names passed to your `Class.create` call, but that will invalidate dead code removal and type checking. If you don't want either of those behaviors, then you should really be using SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.

Your code is also hiding the fact that you have defined properties on `FeedbackController` since Closure-compiler does not recognize that `Class.create` is assigning the properties.

Unless you are willing to change your coding style, I would recommend using SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.

See my [Which Compilation Level is Right for Me?](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html) post for more information on the deciding factors between the optimization levels.

Comment: If you are referring to tobject.toString() then toString() is actually a PrototypeJS function which the compiler is aware of. Thank you for your input though. Much appreciated.